# Is WF applicable to scenarion where there are lot of User Input

Tags: windows, workflow-foundation-4

I have a scenarion where a Screen Appears & user needs to enter some data to it. Then he submits the data on click of a button for a process logic. Based on the data & logic the result can be either True or False.

In case of True the user is allowed to view the next UI where he enters some other set of Data.
In case of False the user stays back in the same screen.

Is the whole an ideal scenario to implement WF?
or WF should be implemented only for the process code when the user submits the data?

Comment: If you don't know what it's for, then why use it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use WF to evaluate a users response.  I do this with a application I manage.  Some data arrives and is shown to the user.  If they click Continue then the data is processed and a new UI is shown.  If they click Delete the data is destroyed and the UI remains the same, waiting to show any new arriving data.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is . I used it to implement a complex rating questionaire (with some complex decisission which questions follows next).